# Hover event on lineargradient colors in svg

Tags: html, d3.js, svg, hover, mousehover

I have an SVG rectangle filled with a lineargradient that has various `<stop offset = ..>` to make it filled with different colours. I'm trying to make a different text appear (one text per colour) every time i hover with the mouse on that specific color. To make it clear:

When i hover over the orange in the rect i want "Orange" to appear.
When i hover over the red in the rect i want "Red" to appear.

But i cannot figure out how to approach this. Is there any way?

Here is my code:

```
<svg>
<g class="nodes">
<rect id="13" class="startNode" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="540" freq="1" ref="13"
    style="fill: url("#fill-13"); cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
</rect>
<linearGradient id="fill-13" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#ffe154; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
    <stop offset="37%" style="stop-color:#ffe154; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
    <stop offset="37%" style="stop-color:#009600; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
    <stop offset="48%" style="stop-color:#009600; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
    <stop offset="48%" style="stop-color:#ff54ff; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
    <stop offset="49%" style="stop-color:#ff54ff; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
    <stop offset="49%" style="stop-color:#5151ff; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
    <stop offset="55%" style="stop-color:#5151ff; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
    <stop offset="55%" style="stop-color:#ff0000; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
    <stop offset="67%" style="stop-color:#ff0000; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
    <stop offset="67%" style="stop-color:#59bdff; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#59bdff; stop-opacity: 1.0"></stop>
</linearGradient>
```

Comment: It would be easier to use several rects each with a different fill color instead of using one rect with a linear gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've commented: It would be easier to use several rects each with a different fill color instead of using one rect with a linear gradient.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg")
svg.addEventListener("mouseover",(e)=>{
  output.innerHTML = e.target.getAttribute("class")
})
```

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<p id="output">color</p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 540" width="50">
  <g class="nodes">
    <rect width="100"  height="37%"
fill="#ffe154" class="yellow"/>
    <rect width="100" y="37%"  height="11%"
fill="#009600" class="green"/>
    <rect width="100" y="48%"  height="1%"
fill="#ff54ff" class="purple"/>
    <rect width="100" y="49%"  height="6%"
fill="#5151ff" class="blue"/>
    <rect width="100" y="55%"  height="12%"
fill="#ff0000" class="red"/>
    <rect width="100" y="67%"  height="33%"
fill="#59bdff" class="skyblue"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved with this approach